# Mule ESB act as proxy for AMQP Service (RabbitMQ)?

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, mule, esb, amqp

All,

We are considering `Vnext ESB` and `Messaging` solutions in my enterprise. Question on a pattern - Would using `Mule ESB` to proxy a messaging solution such as `RabbitMQ` be a viable and supported pattern for `Mule`?

More specifically, the pattern would include hosting a public `JMS Proxy` on `Mule`, `Mule` receives the message using the `JMS` protocol and then transforms it to `AMQP Protocol` before it is sent to `RabbitMQ Queue` on the outbound. If supported, what is the name of this pattern? `Bridge Pattern`? Messaging `Service Proxy Pattern`? Could we employ the `JMS`, `RabbitMQ` and/or `AnyPoint Connectors` to help do this?

The intent for this pattern would be to allow `non-AMQP` supported (e.g. `JMS` only) messaging producers in the enterprise to leverage our potential RabbitMQ messaging solution.

The pattern could be further extended to practically any protocol/transport on the inbound - `SOAP`, `REST`, `Flat file`, etc. Yes? No?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any particular pattern for that. You can simply use any inbound endpoint (JMS, File, JDBC, etc.), then do whatever transformation if required and finally send it to AMQP.

That's one of them main intents of Mule ESB, to abstract you from protocols and transports.

Comment: Seba - Thank you for the quick answer. A clarifying question for you.

Can the Mule JMS Endpoint also act as a service that is being hosted on the Mule ESB listening for inbound JMS messages (e.g. producing application sends its JMS message to what it thinks is an existing JMS queue but is actually a "JMS Proxy" service hosted in Mule. Mule receives the inbound JMS message, does transport protocol negotiation and converts it to AMQP protocol and sends the message out to an external RabbitMQ queue via either a AMQP or RabbitMQ endpoint)?

Comment: It is my understanding that the normal pattern is the Mule JMS endpoint typically en-queues or de-queues messages off of other JMS queues, not act as an inbound listener.

Comment: Mule itself doesn't act as a JMS broker. However, you can run ActiveMQ embedded in Mule, in which case it would be acting as a broker. Then you can add a JMS inbound endpoint and process that message and send it to any other broker.